# Make custom sharepoint 2007 webparts work on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have built a sharepoint webpart in sharepoint 2007. I have used windows server 2003,Visual studio 2010 and sharepoint services 3.0. I need to make this webpart work for sharepoint 2010 also. Is there any way in which I can achieve this? Or is it necessary to create separate webparts each version?

thank you,

Comment: Voting to reopen.  This is not off topic. I'm having the same problem. What could I have done in my code (in general) to make my web part work fine in 2007 but not in 2010 (slow page loading)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the exact functionality and features used by your web part, it may work without change. Have a look at [this series of articles](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html) that I wrote about porting a 2007 solution to 2010.

Comment: I can confirm that the vast majority of our 2007 custom web parts work exactly the same, without modification, in SharePoint 2010. But Muhimbi is right, it will depend on the web part, what it does and how it tries to do it.

Answer (score -1):

yes you have to recreate your webpart as in wss3.0 you reference to microsoft.sharepoint dll of version12.X while in SFS you need to have refrence of 14.X

Comment: There is no need to recreate your web part or change the reference to microsoft.sharepoint.dll unless you are going to add SP2010 specific code.